# Concatanate two columns in a data.frame/file with 1000 columns to one column in a new data.frame/file

Tags: r, bash, function, awk, paste

In my question I mentioned data.frame or file. This means, that I would accept solutions for R as well as for bash. Let's come to my problem.

I have a df/file which have around 1000 columns and 100000 rows. My task is to get out of this df/file a new file where two columns from df1 are combined to one column and are separated by a "/". The tricky thing is, that I want this for all the columns. To make it more clear, here is a example:

df1 with 10 columns

```
a b c d s f r t g g
f j g k r k d a f l 
f p j h g i t b k k
h j l u z b g b d h
```

What I want is the following: df2 with 5 columns

```
a/b c/d s/f r/t g/g
f/j g/k r/k d/a f/l 
f/p j/h g/i t/b k/k
h/j l/u z/b g/b d/h
```

I know that I can combine two columns, delimited by a "/" with the function paste. But unfortunately I don't can figure out how to use it with multiple columns. Maybe it is possible with a "for loop"?

I can imagine that for bash, awk is the solution but I have no idea how it works correctly. Because I have very big files I guess bash is the faster way.

Thanks in advance for helping me.

Best,
Tobi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try

```
df1 <- df[c(TRUE,FALSE)]
df2 <- df[c(FALSE,TRUE)]
as.data.frame(mapply(paste, df1, df2, sep="/"))
#   V1  V3  V5  V7  V9
#1 a/b c/d s/f r/t g/g
#2 f/j g/k r/k d/a f/l
#3 f/p j/h g/i t/b k/k
#4 h/j l/u z/b g/b d/h
```

Or you could do

```
as.data.frame(`dim<-`(paste(as.matrix(df1), 
                as.matrix(df2), sep="/"), dim(df1)))
```

Comment: Notably, 80% of the second solution run time is consumed by the conversions between `data.frame` and `matrix`, so I'd advise @Tobias to avoid using `data.frame` if possible.

Answer (score 2):

In the case you prefer to work with file, you can use perl:

```
cat x.txt | perl -ne '$count = 1; s/ /(++$count % 2 == 0)?"\/":$&/ge;print'
```

To get an idea about the performance of this solution, I generated a large data frame:

```
d <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(letters,size = 10^3*10^5,replace=T,),ncol=10^5))
```

saved it as a text file, and started the perl one-liner, and it took 47.5 seconds on my machine.

For comparison, I also evaluated the run time of the akrun's solution `system.time(df3 <- as.data.frame(mapply(paste, df1, df2, sep="/")))`, and it took 210.6 seconds, i.e. 4-5 times longer. Another solution suggested by akrun, `as.data.frame(`dim<-`(paste(as.matrix(df1), as.matrix(df2), sep="/"), dim(df1)))`, gets it done in 59.7 seconds.